# correctly setting up and using angular with asp.net-mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to learn the correct way of using angular with asp.net-mvc. Right now what I'm doing is letting the asp.net engine render my views, but I'm not passing any information to the view as a model. I'm using `ng-init` to call a scope function to retrieve data as `json`.

for example my index view's get action method is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and I have another controller action method that angular calls:

```
public ActionResult getMembersList()
        {
            List<CommunityMember> cmList = new List<CommunityMember>();
            var members = db.Member.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ToList();
            foreach (var m in members)
            {
                CommunityMember cm = new CommunityMember(m);
                cmList.Add(cm);
            }
            return Json(cmList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

(as an aside, should I avoid this foreach loop? it just creates a list of my CommunityMember viewmodel)

and the angular function looks like this:

```
$scope.getMembersList = function () {
        $http.get("/Members/getMembersList")
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.membersList = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

also all my code for angular is currently in an angular controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('myIndexViewModel', function myIndexViewModel($scope, $http, $compile) {
 //scope functions/variables
 //http calls
 //etc..
}
```

I just feel like this isnt the best approach and want to know if theres a better way to do this. Should I be loading data the way I am through `ng-init` then using the injected `$http` to access the server?

should I put all the `$http` calls in a different place?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside foreach loop what you are making is converting a list of objects to another list of objects.This is so called **mapping(projection)** in functional programming and there is already a linq method to do that. Use **Select**,it is more concise.

```
var members = db.Member.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName)
              .Select(x=>new CommunityMember(){
                                    Name=x.Some,
                                    Age=x.Age
                                }).ToList();
```

The code placed in the controller is not so good. Responsibility of the controller should be data and view not to call services using **$http**. Move the **$http** calls to a custom service that implements promise pattern to notify the controller.Now controller is free from any logic other than updating data that is on the UI.

Try to avoid using Razor for data rendering and keep your front view decocupled from Razor. Js ,html views can be hosted anywhere.You dont have to keep it .Net project too.Make your server side behave as Api layer for your angular application.So make your views static and let angular decide functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed ng-init [isn't the best way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) of getting data from your backend. Instead, you have two other options.

The first one is to resolve *getMembersList* inside your route.

The second one is to resolve *getMembersList* inside your controller, update your scope and then hide your loader.

**Option 1 (using UI-router) :**

```
state('members', {
    url: '/members',
    templateUrl: 'someTemplateURL',
    controller: function(members) {
      //Do something here
    },
    resolve: {
        members: function($http) {
           return  $http.get("/Members/getMembersList")
        }
    }
})
```

**Option 2 (Inside Controller using controllerAs syntax and ES6 fat arrow) :**

```
memberModule.controller('membersCtrl', function ($http) {
    this.loader = true;
    $http.get("/Members/getMembersList")
    .success((data) => {
       this.membersList = data;
       this.loader = false;
       //Your view will pick up the change after the next digest cycle
     })
}
```